# How to write at the next line in the next opening of the csv file?

Tags: c#, winforms, csv, line

At first run, my program, writes to a csv file in the first line,
But, when I'm running my program at the second.. third.. time, it runs over the first line..
how can i correct it?

I would like to have a CSV file input of all the entering to my program.

The code is as follows:

```
private void WriteToCsvFile()
{
    var us = users.ElementAt(0);
    string names = "Number',";
    string userAnswer = (us.userName + ",");
    foreach (string ss in user)
    {
        string str = Path.GetFileName(ss);
        names = names + str + ",";
    }
    foreach (string ans in us.answer)
    {
        userAnswer = userAnswer + ans + ",";
    }

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("EntranceLog.csv"))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(names);
        sw.WriteLine(userAnswer);

    }

    this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `true` parameter in the constructor:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("EntranceLog.csv", true))
```

The second parameter named `append` controls whether an existing file shall be overwritten or appended. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx) states:

> `true` to append data to the file; `false` to overwrite the file. If the specified file does not exist, this parameter has no effect, and the constructor creates a new file.

Answer (score 0):

Each time it is run, you are creating a new file with the same name is overwriting the older file.  That is the default behavior of the specific constructor you are using.

You want to use [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx) instead and specify the `append` parameters as `true`:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("EntranceLog.csv", true))
{
    // write your file as normal
}
```